# White overlay on top of GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to show where blur is - GPUImage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

I want to add a white overlay to the blurred area of GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter, and a custom filter group I built by slightly modifying GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to make rotational tilt shifts (see what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407840/rotate-gpuimagetiltshiftfilter-gpuimage/16407910#16407910)).

I want to modify the shader strings of the filter groups, and I do not want to use a GPUImageVignetteFilter to do the overlay because it won't support a white blur out with the custom tilt shift filter group I have.

Here's what I want the white blur out to look like with tilt shifts:
[image: gpu image rotation]
<sub>(source: [kevinharringtonphoto.com](http://www.kevinharringtonphoto.com/photos/i-r9kQ8pz/0/S/i-r9kQ8pz-S.png))</sub>